# Adding an activation layer to Keras Add() layer and using this layer as output to model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to apply a `softmax activation layer` to the output of the `Add()` layer. I am trying to make this layer the output of my model and I am running into a few problems.

It seems `Add()` layer doesn't allow the usage of activations and if I do something like this:

```
predictions = Add()([x,y])
predictions = softmax(predictions)
model = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Add layer, you are using `K.softmax` directly on Keras tensors and this won't work, you need an actual layer. You can use the `Activation` layer for this:

```
from keras.layers import Activation

predictions = Add()([x,y])
predictions = Activation("softmax")(predictions)
model = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = predictions)
```